# C# linq lambda expression for OR in a list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this scenario in which i query with FindByMany (which takes the lambda and returns post if user country and category matches, (as seen in the "else")
But now i need to customize the return with prefered subcategories from users, so what im doing is query n times foreach subcategory and just addRange. I dont want to query 5 times the db if the user has 5 subcategories as favorite, but i dont know how to apply a dinamic OR.

So my question is, how can this code be improved for performance.

```
var posts = new List<Content>();
if (request.UserId != 0)
{
   var user = _userRepository.FindBy(u => u.Id == request.UserId);
   if (user != null && user.SubCategories.Any())
   {
      foreach (var temp in user.SubCategories.Select(subCategory => _contentRepository.FindManyBy(
         c =>
           c.Country.Id == country.Id && c.Category.Id == theCategory.Id &&
           c.SubCategory.Id == subCategory.Id).ToList()))
      {
         posts.AddRange(temp);
      }
   }
}
else
{
   posts = _contentRepository.FindManyBy(
           c => c.Country.Id == country.Id && c.Category.Id == theCategory.Id
      ).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you not just materalise the sub-categories into a list, and then in your `FindBy` use a `thatlist.Contains()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user's sub-categories with one query and then use the list and the `Contains` method to filter the relevant posts. `Contains` method is supported by most LINQ query provides and should be translated into a single database query.

```
var subcategories = user.SubCategories.ToList();
foreach (var temp in _contentRepository.FindManyBy(
     c =>
       c.Country.Id == country.Id && c.Category.Id == theCategory.Id &&
      subcategories.Contains( subCategory.Id ) ).ToList()))
 {
    posts.AddRange(temp);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build expression for where clause using [Expression.OrElse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353063%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or use [enter link description here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The core of the problem is that you're forcing query execution for each item instead of dynamically building the query. @Milney has the right idea; example code below.

```
IEnumerable<int> subCategoryIds = user.SubCategories.Select(x => x.Id);
var posts = _contentRepository.FindByMany(c => c.Country.Id == country.Id 
    && c.Category.Id == theCategory.Id 
    && subCategoryIds.Contains(c.SubCategoryId)).ToList();
```